# thymeleaf sax parser and utm_source

Tags: saxparser, thymeleaf

Processing a template with thymeleaf with "utm_source" even under a href property causes a failure.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 315; columnNumber: 126; The reference to entity "utm_source" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Does any one know a workaround for this? Since it's a like if I transform to a HTML code it fails then because there are && together.

Also, this is probably more related to SAX Parser than thymeleaf.

Comment: can you please add the template code so that we can review it?

Answer (score 0):

Escaping with & works. Example:

```
<a href="www.example.com/?utm_abc=xyz&amp;utm_source=def"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link parameters should be done like so:

```
<a th:href="@{${baseUrl}(param1=value1,param2=value2)}">
```

Source:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html